# How to make jQuery changes to <select> dropdown register in the HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a project with a large dynamic form. The form can be manipulated by jQuery and saved as HTML (to be outputted to a PDF).

When changes are made to `<select>` dropdowns the change isn't reflected in the HTML, so when the form is saved the wrong option is displayed.

Code Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/n4bxzr49/1

```
<p>Original Form</p>
<form id="form">
<select id="select">
  <option value="apple">Apple</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="carrot">Carrot</option>
</select>
</form>
<p>Form Saved then Loaded via jQuery</p>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#select').val('carrot');
var formHTML = $('#form').html();
$('#output').html(formHTML);
```

Returns:

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? What is the best alternative for setting the value of a `<select>` dropdown in jQuery so it also shows in the HTML?

Comment: what you want is when changes is made on the dropdown you want to pass that value to the output `div`

Comment: is this something what you want done mate ? http://jsfiddle.net/n4bxzr49/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually set `selected` attribute. It will not be reflected in the html when you change the selected `property` in the dom

Can do something like:

```
$('option:selected').attr('selected',true);
```

Note that you will have the same issue with any `<input>` whereby the attribute `value` will not reflect user changes. There is a difference between *attribute value* and *value property*

For text inputs you could do something like:

```
$('input:text').attr('value',function(){
   return this.value;
});
```

For checked radios and checkbox you need to set `checked` attribute something like:

```
$('input:checked').attr('checked',true)
```

In other words, to answer your question, the behavior you are seeing is as expected

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n4bxzr49/7/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any jQuery plugins which go through a form and make sure all of the DOM values are reflected in the HTML?